# layout xml positioning syling

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

i dont know much about styling a layout, i want that some object will be attached to the right side of the creen, and some will be attached to the left side of the screen.

I have this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

     <TextView android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
         android:text="TextView" />

     <TextView android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
         android:text="TextView" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/score"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
         android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
         android:gravity="center_vertical"
         android:text="TextView"
         android:textColor="#000000"
         android:textSize="22dp"
         android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

i want that the `TextView` `score` will be at the left side of the screen; i mean that left will be 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a horizontal `LinearLayout`, views are displayed from left to right. So, if you want `score` to be fixed at the left, you have to put it, inside the `LinearLayout`, but before both `name` and `date`.

If you want another view to be fixed to the right, you have to make the "middle" view to fill the remaining space. You usually would do this by setting its `layout_width`to 0dp and it's `layout_weight`to 1.

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView
     android:id="@+id/score"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
     ... />

 <TextView android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    ... />

 <TextView android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    ... />

</LinearLayout>
```

If you need more flexibility, try using a `RelativeLayout` instead.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

`android:layout_gravity="right"`  or `"left"`

Answer (score 1):

```
// try this way let me know still have some problem.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/score"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```